Remove light/dark theme management in jupyterbook
I created a Jupyter Book and I want to disable the light/dark theme management option.
I managed to find that this can be potentially customized by modifying some options in the sphinx section of the _config.yaml file.
More specifically, looking at this PyData Sphinx Theme documentation, it can be seen that by both specifying the default_mode and removing the theme-switcher from the navbar_end section, the dark/light theme button should be disabled.
So I added the following lines to my _config.yaml file, but it had no effect:
sphinx:
  config:
    html_context:
      default_mode: light
    html_theme_options:
      # ...
      navbar_end:
        - navbar-icon-links

Can't tell if my options are incorrect or if they are getting overwritten during the build process, so any hints on what might be going on are greatly appreciated.

If suddenly you don't find a better solution, you can use a crutch:

Create a _static folder in the project directory
In the _static folder, create a script.js file with the contents:

window.onload = (event) => {
    var mode_elem = document.querySelector("[aria-label='light/dark']");
    mode_elem.remove();
};

This removes your icon after the page loads.
But there's probably a better solution.

I recently tried to find out how to set the default mode to "light". So the same as your request except for the html_theme_options-part. It worked for me after added recursive_update: true:
sphinx:
  recursive_update: true
  config:
    html_context:
      default_mode: light

Maybe it also works for you :)
